# What should the tag wiki excerpts for language-specific tags be?

Tags: discussion, tags

Usually, language-specific tags have this excerpt:

> This challenge is intended to utilize the _____ language as a means of solving a problem. However, language-specific challenges are generally discouraged on CG.

However, the problem is that sometimes, questions tagged with the language tags are not asking for solutions in that language; rather, the challenge is simply related to the language. For example, my challenge [Minify BF](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/16732/3808).

How could the standard excerpt be changed to rectify this?

I don't want to just make an executive decision, because I would have to update all the tags without any community input, but I went ahead and posted my suggestion in the answers below. If the community is in general agreement on one suggestion, I'll go ahead and edit all the language tags' excerpts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My suggestion is to change it to

> This challenge is related to the _____ language. Note that challenges that require the answers to be in a specific language are generally discouraged.

It's both short enough to fit and gets the message across.

Comment: I have edited all of the language tags. Therefore, I will accept this answer.