# The Tag Categorization Project

Tags: discussion, tags

This is not a question; rather, it is a collection of categories of tags.

The purpose of this post is to post information regarding specific categories, such as templates for tag wikis, and also to consolidate all of the tag categories in one place.

Please edit the categories below if you find a missing tag (they are Community Wiki), or add a new answer if you have a new category.

Comment: Given that the winning criteria answer has been [superseded](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22371/66833) by an [faq] post, the language tag answer was, until the most recent edit, completely out of date and seemingly unnecessary, *and* this has gone 8 years without another category being proposed, I'm VTCing this as a dupe of the linked FAQ post

Answer (score 17):

## Winning Criteria/Question Type

**Every** question should have at least one of these tags.

Please use [this search query](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22%22+is%3Aquestion+closed%3Ano+-%5Bcode-golf%5D+-%5Bcode-challenge%5D+-%5Bpopularity-contest%5D+-%5Bfastest-code%5D+-%5Bfewest-operations%5D+-%5Bcode-trolling%5D+-%5Bcode-bowling%5D+-%5Bbusy-beaver%5D+-%5Bking-of-the-hill%5D+-%5Batomic-code-golf%5D+-%5Bcode-shuffleboard%5D+-%5Btips%5D+-%5Bchallenge-writing%5D+-%5Bprogramming-puzzle%5D+-%5Brestricted-source%5D+-%5Balgorithm%5D+-%5Bmetagolf%5D+-%5Bfastest-algorithm%5D+-%5Bpuzzle-solver%5D+-%5Banswer-chaining%5D++-%5Bcops-and-robbers%5D+-%5Btest-battery%5D+-%5Brosetta-stone%5D+-%5Bproof-golf%5D+-%5Bshowcase%5D+-%5Bself-scoring%5D) to find questions without one, and tag with the correct tag if the winning criterion is specified in the question. Currently (Feb. 6, 2022) there are none!

If you think there needs to be a new category, post an answer to the [Let's create some new types of challenges!](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1288/9498).

- [answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining) - Challenge where each answer influences how newer answers work. Often ends when there are no new answer in a specific time and the last one wins.
- [atomic-code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atomic-code-golf) - Challenge with limited amounts of commands available, shortest wins.
- [busy-beaver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/busy-beaver) - Challenge where the answer who gets the largest value of a certain computation model property wins, subject to the constraint that it must halt.
- [challenge-writing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/challenge-writing) - Question about writing challenges, not necessarily for CGCC.
- [code-bowling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-bowling) - Challenge to solve a problem in the most bytes or complexity.
- [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) - Challenge with a specific scoring system, that isn't covered by any other tag.
- [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) - Challenge to solve a problem in the least bytes of source code.
- [code-shuffleboard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-shuffleboard) - Challenge to solve a problem in a given amount of bytes.
- [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) - Challenge covering 2 sub-challenges, where one's target is to solve a problem, and the second's is to find a hole in the first.
- [fastest-algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-algorithm) - Challenge won by the answer with the smallest asymptotic time complexity. Don't mistake with fastest-code.
- [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) - Challenge where the winner is determined by the runtime performance of the code.
- [fewest-operations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fewest-operations) - Challenge to solve a problem in the least amount of specified operations. Basically the [atomic-code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atomic-code-golf) of [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code).
- [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) - Challenge where submissions interact with and compete against each other in a form of a game.
- [metagolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metagolf) - Challenge to solve a problem in the least amount of bytes in the output.
- [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) - Challenge where the answer with the highest vote tally wins.
- [programming-puzzle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-puzzle) (ex. [When is a giraffe not a giraffe?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12188/3808)) - Challenge where a program is given and submission has to edit it so it solves a specified problem.
- [proof-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-golf) - Challenge to solve a particular theorem/statement in the fewest number of substitutions/steps given a set of axioms.
- [rosetta-stone](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rosetta-stone) - Challenge where the goal is to write a solution using as many programming languages as possible.
- [self-scoring](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-scoring) - Challenge whose scoring criterion involves passing a program itself as input
- [test-battery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test-battery) - Challenge whose scoring criterion involves running the output of a program through a large number of test cases.
- [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) - Question asking for tips on a specific piece of code, to make it a better answer to a programming challenge.
- [showcase](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/showcase) - [This question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44680/showcase-of-languages). Please **do not** create additional [showcase](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/showcase) questions

Comment: [code-tounament] seems to be redundant at this point with [king-of-the0hill] (or vice versa). [rosetta-stone] seems ill defined as does [puzzle]. [code-challenge]'s wiki should indicate that is the the fallback tag for puzzles that don't conform to any defined category, rather than being applied to everything other than [code-golf].

Comment: @dmckee I agree with tournament and king of hill. Rosetta stone just means lots of languages, so maybe it doesn't fit here and should always be accompanied with another tag. And yes, I agree that code challenge is just our fallback. Maybe I'll elaborate or fix some of these when I get to a computer (I'm on mobile now)

Comment: @dmckee Done. Killed [code-tournament], removed [rosetta-stone] from post and added example of [puzzle], edited [tag:code-challenge] wiki.

Comment: What about [tag:underhanded]? Seems like a question-type, but doesn't necessarily cover the winning criteria.

Comment: With respect to @Mego's recent edit, I'm certain that [tag:multiple-holes] and [tag:polyglot] don't belong on the list, but I'm not sure about [tag:answer-chaining] or [tag:cops-and-robbers]. Those aren't winning conditions in themselves, are they?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I agree with multiple holes and polyglot; I'll remove them in the morning if they haven't been fixed by then. I'm not sure why I added them. Answer chaining and CnR have winning conditions - be the last answer by a certain cutoff and have the best score without being cracked by some cutoff, respectively. I don't know which of the other tags would be appropriate, other than code challenge (which doesn't seem like a good fit).

Answer (score 6):

## Language Tags

The desired tag wiki excerpt for these tags is:

> This challenge is related to the _____ language. Note that challenges that require the answers to be in a specific language are generally discouraged.

[(relevant meta post)](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/904/3808)

[apl](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apl)
[assembly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assembly)
[bash](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bash)
[basic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/basic)
[befunge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/befunge)
[brain-flak](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brain-flak)
[brainfuck](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brainfuck)
[c](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c)
[c#](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%23)
[c++](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)
[cjam](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cjam)
[css](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/css)
[cubically](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cubically)
[deadfish](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deadfish)
[golfscript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/golfscript)
[haskell](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haskell)
[java](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java)
[javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript)
[jelly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jelly)
[json](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/json)
[klein](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/klein)
[lean](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lean)
[lisp](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lisp)
[lost](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lost)
[lua](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lua)
[matlab](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matlab)
[octave](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/octave)
[perl](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/perl)
[php](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/php)
[powershell](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powershell)
[prelude](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prelude)
[pyth](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pyth)
[python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python)
[r](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r)
[ruby](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ruby)
[scala](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scala)
[sql](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql)
[starry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starry)
[swift](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swift)
[vyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vyxal)
[x86-family](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x86-family)

Comment: To be frank, a lot of these tags have no good reason to exist. In cases where the only tagged question is the [tag:tips] one, the language tag doesn't really add anything.

Comment: They add the ability to *follow*. Even if the tag has nothing but a tips tag now, following enables future activity to connect with an audience. There *are* cases of language-agnostic challenges that could be or already are tagged with a language tag, for example [Brainf**k Debugger](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22585/brainfk-debugger) or [C code indenter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/20328/c-code-indenter/20839#20839). I'm not saying we should spam out empty tags for every language, but I see no reason to deny those that have any posts their existence.

Comment: With the addition of "featured languages", this post may become more useful than it was previously.