# Should there be a [restricted-source] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've noticed lots of questions that restrict the source code in some way. For example, "do xxxxx without using xxxxx characters."

Should there be a tag for this? This way these types of questions could be categorized more easily.

If so, could I have any help finding all the questions to retag? :P

Comment: I think that in most cases it would be appropriate to take a hint from http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/18865/194 and tag them [tag:stupid-restrictions]. Yet another bandwagon which people are jumping on without giving through to whether their question is remotely interesting.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Actually, these have been around for quite a while, ex. http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/307/3808

Comment: This is true, but something doesn't have to be new to be a bandwagon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to go ahead and add this tag to all of these in 3 days if nobody objects.

My reasoning is that first, *all* questions should have [a winning criteria/question type](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/908/3808). [This search query](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?page=1&tab=votes&q=%22%22%20is%3aquestion%20closed%3ano%20-%5bcode-golf%5d%20-%5bcode-challenge%5d%20-%5bpopularity-contest%5d%20-%5bfastest-code%5d%20-%5bcode-trolling%5d%20-%5bcode-bowling%5d%20-%5bbusy-beaver%5d%20-%5bking-of-the-hill%5d%20-%5batomic-code-golf%5d%20-%5bcode-shuffleboard%5d%20-%5btips%5d%20-%5bpuzzle%5d) that I put together that searches for questions without one of these tags reveals lots of restricted-source challenges.

Also, we need better organization if we want to get out of beta any time soon. If we do become a full-fledged SE site, much more content will start appearing, and we need to keep it clean and organized.

If anyone thinks the name could be improved, feel free to comment and suggest another tag name. Otherwise, since nobody has said anything else about this, I'll just add the tag so I get get on with my tag categorization project.

-- 3 days later edit --

I am now editing all the posts; therefore, I shall accept this answer.