# When is a (new) language-specific tag appropriate?

Tags: discussion, tags

```
LanguageSpecificTag languagespecifictag = new LanguageSpecificTag();
```

---

In [@Doorknob's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3808/doorknob) [Tag Categorization Project](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/907/46231), there's [an answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/907/46231) outlining language-specific tags.

The answer notes the format of these tags' wikis:

> This challenge is related to the _____ language. Note that challenges that require the answers to be in a specific language are generally discouraged.

There are 134 questions tagged [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips), and that's where *most* of the relevancy for these lang-specific tags comes in.

In [the comments to that answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/906/the-tag-categorization-project?lq=1#comment3234_907), [@Peter Taylor](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/194/peter-taylor) noted (with 10 comment votes*):

> To be frank, a lot of these tags have no good reason to exist. In cases where the only tagged question is the tips one, the language tag doesn't really add anything.

Aha! But, [@Jonathan Van Matre](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3363/jonathan-van-matre) [responded validly](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/906/the-tag-categorization-project?lq=1#comment4729_907) (with 6 comment votes*) that:

> They add the ability to follow. Even if the tag has nothing but a [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) tag now, following enables future activity to connect with an audience. [...] [language-agnostic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic) challenges [...] could be or already are tagged with a language tag. [...] **I'm not saying we should spam out empty tags for every language, but I see no reason to deny those that have any posts their existence.**

---

The reason I'm writing this question is that within the last week, I've asked [two](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/74359/46231) [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips)  [questions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/74436/tips-for-golfing-in-pike) which I was slightly tempted to tag with [pike](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pike) and [d-lang](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/d-lang) respectively.

I did not do this, because it felt rather abusive to make two rather pointless tags for two little-known languages, just because I wrote a [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) question.

On the other hand, [javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and [c](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c) and [python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) and [perl](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/perl) all exist with more than just [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) to their names, while some other language-specific tags have only one [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) question.

**When is it okay to make a new language-specific tag?** Should we "spam out empty tags for every language", or should we *only* tolerate tags that have [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) *and* at least one challenge? I feel there's a lack of consensus, and that having one would be constructive.

---

<sup>* counting mine, because i really don't know which way i'd go</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### On existing tags

Language-specific tags are useful in two scenarios:

1. Challenges involving parsing, interpreting, or outputting code in a specific language, as is the case with many challenges bearing the [brainfuck](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brainfuck) tag.
2. Challenges that *are* language-specific.

"But wait," you say, "I thought language-specific challenges were discouraged!" And in general they are. The most notable exception is [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) challenges. Most of these require the use of a specific language so that the submissions can interact with a controller written by the OP. Having a language tag on these challenges helps identify which language is required.

Another example recently that was popular, albeit rather contentious, was [A little bool magic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/74384/20469), which required the use of C#. Regardless of whether pure programming puzzles are on topic, challenges such as these should also bear a tag denoting the required language.

I certainly don't think we need the mass of language tags that we currently have, particularly those whose only question is a [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips). In fact, I think that all such tags should be eventually be removed (*not all at once*). If there is a tag with a *good* language-specific challenge, the tag should probably stay. Also, if there are challenges that involve parsing a language, that tag should stay.

### When is it appropriate to make a new one?

Most of the time it isn't. If you're making a [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) question, don't make a new language tag. If you're making some kind of language-specific challenge such as a [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) or [programming-puzzle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-puzzle), go ahead and make the tag. If you're making a challenge that involves parsing a language, make the tag if it's a notable language (e.g. Brainfuck). In this case, use good judgement for when a language would be deemed "notable" and thus worthy of its own tag.

In any case, add the standard note to the tag wiki:

> This challenge is related to the _____ language. Note that challenges that require the answers to be in a specific language are generally discouraged.

Comment: Great answer, thank you!~

Comment: One  (very common) case you didn't mention is challenges *about* certain languages. Just have a look around the [brainfuck] or [befunge] (that is challenges which are about writing an interpreter for our generating code in the language).

Comment: @MartinBüttner How's this?

Comment: @AlexA. Sounds good. I guess as soon as we have two challenges *about* a language I'd also call it relevant/notable enough to warrant a tag (mostly for the reason of "hey I liked writing code about this language, is there more like this?")