# Tagging programming puzzles that are not code-golf?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm new to this site, and I see that it is called "Programming Puzzles & Code Golf", and that its url is https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

If I look at the front page of questions, I see that almost all of them have a tag called "code-golf": https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOlh9.jpg (I'm not including the image inline here, because it's rather long).

Looking through the history, it is awfully hard to find questions that are not tagged code-golf, and are still open / have positive votes. But after figuring out [the search syntax](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aquestion%20-%5bcode-golf%5d%20closed%3ano), I find that the following are the ones asked in 2017:

- [Kolmogorov Complexity Meta Golfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/108536/kolmogorov-complexity-meta-golfer)
- [Q: OOP: Overlapping Oriented Programming](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/108075/oop-overlapping-oriented-programming)
- [Find the shortest Golomb rulers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/108044/find-the-shortest-golomb-rulers)
- [Fastest Home Prime Generator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/108006/fastest-home-prime-generator)
- [Output a program that outputs a program … that outputs PPCG](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/107944/output-a-program-that-outputs-a-program-that-outputs-ppcg)
- [Total Derangement (Difficulty Level: Hard)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/107814/total-derangement-difficulty-level-hard)
- [The Tax Historian](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/107812/the-tax-historian)
- [Count spelling errors in text; minimize the number of spelling errors in your code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/107690/count-spelling-errors-in-text-minimize-the-number-of-spelling-errors-in-your-co)
- [Do you know that language?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/107322/do-you-know-that-language)
- [Display OEIS sequences](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/107209/display-oeis-sequences)
- [Exit Code Golfing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/107193/exit-code-golfing)
- [Hidden Inversions (Cops' Thread)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/107012/hidden-inversions-cops-thread) and [Hidden Inversions (Robbers' Thread)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/107014/hidden-inversions-robbers-thread)
- [Split arrays and programs in half](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/107000/split-arrays-and-programs-in-half)
- [Python workarounds for assignment in lambda](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/106514/python-workarounds-for-assignment-in-lambda)
- [Sharing (characters) is Caring!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/106279/sharing-characters-is-caring)
- [Combinatory Conundrum!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/105991/combinatory-conundrum)
- [2016 Time Capsule String: Climb The Integer Ladder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/105558/2016-time-capsule-string-climb-the-integer-ladder)
- [2016 Time Capsule String: How Versatile Is Your Language?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/105398/2016-time-capsule-string-how-versatile-is-your-language)

Many of these questions are highly voted, though some have very few answers. Some are related to code-golf (like the Python tips question), but some are not. And I really enjoy the questions that are not code-golf.

Which brings me to my question: given that most questions on this site are code-golf, would it help to have a tag for questions that are *not* code-golf, so that they can be easier to find? (Of course in the process of asking the question I figured out a [search query](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aquestion%20-%5bcode-golf%5d%20closed%3ano) that I can use personally, but I wonder if there are other people who might be interested in such questions.)

Comment: Welcome to the site! There are a few different tags that the non-code-golf questions fall into: [fastest-code](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/fastest-code/info), [king-of-the-hill](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/king-of-the-hill/info), [cops-and-robbers](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/cops-and-robbers/info), [answer-chaining](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/answer-chaining/info), the aforementioned [tips](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/tips/info), and ...

Comment: ... [code-challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-challenge/info), which is something of an "everything else" category (but must still have an objective scoring method). There's also [popularity-contest](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/popularity-contest/info), but those are hard to do well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, such a tag would not be useful. Tags describe what challenges *are*, not what they *are not*.

Code golf challenges are the most popular type of challenge on this site, so it can be hard to find challenges that aren't code golf. You can use [this list of tags](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/908/45941) to find challenges with other winning criteria.

Comment: Thanks, I'm marking this answer as accepted because it's clear that the community consensus is against a "not-code-golf" tag, and more importantly because that exhaustive list of challenge-type tags (assuming every question has one of them) will serve the purpose quite nicely.

Answer (score 2):

## No, adding [not-code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/not-code-golf) would have no use

You can already search for things that are not tagged [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) with `-[code-golf]`.  So there would no help people who are searching for them.  In addition it would add an extra tag to pretty much every [atomic-code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atomic-code-golf), [metagolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metagolf), [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill), etc. challenge. This would knock tags off of questions that are already at the tag limit.  This would overall make it *harder* for users to find challenges they like that are not [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf).