# Do we have Programming Puzzles where the CodeGolf'ing is not the criteria and actually disallowed?

Tags: discussion

When I searched with -[code-golf] i did not get interesting results.
I am looking for the questions (and as popular as CodeGolf questions) that disallow or not require the Code to be golfed to Bytes. Just some programming puzzles offering fun/interesting challenges and solutions in various languages.

Comment: [tag:code-challenge]

Comment: The reason you are seeing mostly [tag:code-golf] challenges is because it fits pretty much any problem.  I can say "Write an algorithm to do X", and [tag:code-golf] is easy to apply, where [tag:fastest-code] and [tag:fastest-algorithm] aren't.

Comment: Nobody can "*disallows*" one to golf their code, as long as it's a serious contender.

Comment: Although it's very difficult to post one that fits the scope and is well received now, in the past there were many popularity contests, many of which have answers with readable, well explained code. It might be worth browsing that tag if you're looking for interesting challenges without strict rules. That does mean some of them have been closed as off topic, but there are still lots of older ones still open to new answers

Comment: A link to [non-closed popularity contests highest voted first](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=closed%3a0%20is%3aq%20%5bpopularity-contest%5d)

Comment: Here's a [list of all challenge types](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/908/20260).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## There are other, active, alternatives

Our on-topic page says (in part):

> All challenge questions on this site should have: [...]
>   An objective primary winning criterion, so that it is possible to indisputably decide which entry should win.

This is a fundamental pillar of the site. As a consequence, [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) is by far our most popular winning criterion, with 8359 out of the 9979 total questions marked with that tag. For the most part, this is because the tag is easy to apply, easy to score, and easy to use. It provides easy objectivity, and an easy way to meet that requirement.

However, there certainly are other popular tags:

- [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill), a tournament-style competition between various bots, with unique scoring per challenge. Especially recently, this tag has become quite popular, with ten challenges in the past two months.
- [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers), a competitive-programming challenge, where one person tries to obfuscate code in some specified manner, and others try to crack the obfuscation.
- [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge), pretty much a catch-all for challenges that have uniquely defined scoring criteria.
- [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code), exactly what it says on the tin.
- etc.