# Can we link canonical meta posts (e.g "what is a quine", standard loopholes) more actively on the site?

Tags: discussion

I mostly ask this for the benefit of new users (e.g. me, ish), who might not *know* where all the important meta things are, especially since they're not linked every time they apply.  I've done some looking and I'm still not sure if I know where all of the canonical posts *are.*

Comment: Alternatively, an index of canonical posts would be good too.

Comment: Not an answer, but tag info pages already have links to the appropriate pages.

Comment: Oh.  That's very not obvious.

Comment: Also, do posts like standard loopholes even have a tag they're associated with?

Comment: That'd be all challenge type specifying tags. All challenges (so, not [tag:tips] posts) must have at least one such tag.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a tag that links to standard loopholes?

Comment: [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/quine/info) but I noticed that some that should (e.g. [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info)) don't do that. Maybe we should have a pass at fixing them all?

Comment: I would certainly recommend that!

Comment: Then I suggest you make a new post asking for that. The current set of winning criteria is listed [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/908/43319).

Comment: That's probably a good idea, too.  But I do think that even the tags that definitely *do* have canonical posts linked could benefit from some more active prompting for new users, so I'm going to leave this here.

Comment: If only we could edit the help pages beyond the [on-topic section](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Some of the stuff (like [what types of questions should I avoid asking](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)) don't even make much sense in the context of PPCG :(

Comment: What do you mean you can't edit that?  I thought you could.

Comment: Nope! I'm pretty sure it is only the on-topic page that the moderators can edit. Every other page is generic trash for all of Stack Exchange, occasionally substituting the words `programming puzzles and code golf` as the stack name. A lot of it is geared toward Q&A sites (which we're not), so it is counter-productive to actually helping people understand what we do here