# Tags that should have references to standard loopholes, I/O standards, etc., do not

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-wikis

Looking at the various winning criteria tags in [The Tag Categorization Project](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/906/the-tag-categorization-project/908#908), a lot of them should have links to helpful resources such as the standard loopholes and I/O standards in their wikis, but currently don't

This probably should be fixed.

Comment: n.b I have no idea how to tag this.  My apologies if I have erred.

Comment: I've added some I think fit.

Comment: Do you mean that the tag descriptions themselves should reference SL and IO Standards, or that all challenges using those tags should?

IMO, the whole point of SL and IO Standards is that they are **standard**, aka implied unless otherwise stated.

Comment: @Skidsdev They mean that the tag descriptions/wikis should link. Yes they are by default, but it is one more chance (albeit small) that people will see them.

Answer (score 3):

Not all tag wikis need links to the standard loopholes and the I/O formats, especially as they can be found in the [site FAQ](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1280/66833). However, the [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) tag wiki, which is most likely to need them, now has links to [both](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info) (and more helpful links), so this is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)